# prevent redirect by isp when credit expires redirect to my app page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, phonegap

Ihave a phonegap app, i have put all measeures

```
<access origin="*://*.mysite/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```

when my data credit expires, i get a redirect to ISP remote page, which i don't want.

how can i modify my config file or my  index page to avoid redirect or redirect to internal source if credit expires.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://*.myweb http://myweb/tribes/shopmobile.php  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src 'self'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons;img-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css 'self' http://myweb/ data:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' http://myweb data:;child-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com data:;frame-src *;">
```

I used the above csp on my app 
To allow internal links 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'-allow external and internal styles
script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'-to allow all js scripts
img-src 'self' http://myweb data: allow images from my server
content="default-src 'self' http://*.myweb http://myweb/tribes/shopmobile.php  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com  allow data from my server only

the above code worked